# dynamic list of parameters without having repeated parameter name

Tags: android, retrofit

I have my rest api like:

```
http://MY_SERVER/api/story?feed_ids=1,2,3&page=1
```

here i should provide *dynamic* list of feed_ids separated by comma, 
for that i wrote my rest service like:

```
@GET("/story")
void getStory( @Query("feed_ids") List<Integer> feed_items, @Query("page") int  page,Callback<StoryCollection> callback);
```

and:

```
private List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); // items is a list of  feed ids subscribed by user (retrieved from app db). initialization is done here just for testing 

public void getLatestStoryCollection(int page ,Callback<StoryCollection> callback) {
            newsService.getStory(items,  page ,callback);
}
```

my code runs fine but retrofit sends request url like:

```
http://MY_SERVER/api/story?feed_ids=1&feed_ids=2&feed_ids=3&page=1
```

is there a way to send such dynamic list of parameters just like `feed_ids=1,2,3` without having repeated parameter name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom class that overrides `toString()` to format them as a comma-separated list. Something like:

```
class FeedIdCollection extends List<Integer> {
    public FeedIdCollection(int... ids) {
        super(Arrays.asList(ids));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return TextUtils.join(",", this);
    }
}
```

And then make your declaration:

```
@GET("/story")
void getStory( @Query("feed_ids") FeedIdCollection feed_items, @Query("page") int page, Callback<StoryCollection> callback);
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more. It changes extends to implements and super takes 0 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do it in retrofit, but you can do it pretty easily yourself.  Since you are using android, you can use [`TextUtils.join()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable)) to convert any list to a String.  Then pass that string to as your query parameter instead of a list.  First, update your interface to take a `String` instead of a `List`.

```
@GET("/story")
void getStory( @Query("feed_ids") String feed_items, @Query("page") int page, Callback<StoryCollection> callback);
```

then when you call your `getStory` method, pass the items through `join` first --

```
String items = TextUtils.join(",", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
newsService.getStory(items, page, callback);
```